# Knockout difference between normal javascript function and a computed

Tags: knockout.js

It seems I can write a function on my view model in two ways with the same result.

Normal javascript function:

```
vm.Texts = function () {
  var self = vm;
  if (self.selectedFormat()) {
    return self.selectedFormat().Texts();
  }
};
```

ko computed:

```
vm.Texts = ko.computed(function () {
  var self = vm;
  if (self.selectedFormat()) {
    return self.selectedFormat().Texts();
  }
});
```

'vm' is the view model and selectedFormat is an observable on the view model. In both cases when selectedFormat changes the function is triggered. So my question is what is the difference between the two methods?

Comment: In your html how are you using your `Texts` function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm supposing a data-binding along these lines:

```html
<span data-bind="text: Texts()"></span>
```

**Bottom line**:
In both cases **the `text` binding will create a dependency on `selectedFormat`** on initial rendering.

---

**Details:**
Both of your situations will update the `span` because:

1. **Function  case**. The `text` binding will notice on initial rendering that there's a dependency on the `selectedFormat` observable because it's being called in your function. If the observable ever changes it will find that dependency in KO's registers and trigger an update on the `text` binding. The dependency looks like this:

   `text binding --> depends-indirectly-on --> selectedFormat`

   See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LgkbJ/).
2. **Computed case**. The second case may work the same, though it's slightly more obvious, because `Texts` is now dependent on a (computed) observable that acts as an intermediary to the `selectedFormat` observable. The dependency is now:

   `text binding --> depends-on --> Texts computed --> depends-on --> selectedFormat`

   See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wC37F/).